# How do I deal with failure so early on?

Tags: phd, exams

I'm in my first year of a STEM PhD and had to sit some exams as part of an external training course. Out of the two I had to do, I failed the first one by 4 points and I'm feeling really rough about it. I'm concerned I'm going to lose my studentship when the time for annual reviews comes around.

How do I deal with failure/setbacks so early on?

Comment: You should talk to your supervisor asap. Not only will they reassure you (I honestly think it's very unlikely your studentship would be revoked due to not passing some external exam) but they will know exactly what the rules and possible outcomes are. Don't wait another 3+ months for your annual review, stewing and stressing. Pull the plaster off quickly and move on.

Comment: Failure early on? Reminds me of Linus from Peanuts. "Only four years old and I'm already illiterate!"

Comment: Have you ever failed an exam before? No? Welcome to postgraduate education.

Answer (score 4):

As simple or naive as this may sound, the best solution is to learn from your mistakes, but not to dwell on them. You failed an exam and this may have consequences, but you cannot go back in the past and change it. It is important that you try to look at your corrected exam copy, understand your mistakes and learn from them. You can also look at what happened during and before the exam and understand what lead you to failure. Is your study method adequate? Were you at the last minute? What was lacking in your preperation?

Failure is normal, do not feel guilt over it. The important is to be able to move on from failure and to learn from your mistakes in order to succeed afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, part of the reason I'm upset is because they won't give me my corrected script back. The only comments I received were "too many errors to pass"

Comment: Then those are the rules and you will have to live with them, regrettably. You can try to ask for a meeting with the person that gave the exam in order to discuss the errors you made. Sometimes evaluators will not want to hand over a copy of the exam because they want to be able to reuse the material later on.

Comment: Good advice here. Work hard to get some feedback so that you can do the suggested retrospective. If necessary ask for a meeting in which you ask what the main issues are and how the prof suggests you address them. Even if you don't get a meeting (though you should) you telegraph your seriousness.